# Install Canon Pixma MX350 series printer in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

Can anyone point me in the direction of a **USEFUL** guide for installing the Canon Pixma MX350 series printer? I'm running Ubuntu 20.04LTS and so far my searches have taken me to PPAs that don't work, links to guides in German and numerous other 'solutions' offered up in a most inexpert manner.
I've had the printer running before but after a fresh install of my OS, it no longer works. Thanks in advance,
Phil

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. A work-around but it did the trick: create a Windows virtual machine (Wine's a pain so not an option), run the .exe printer setup by capturing the host optical drive and install. I wasn't looking forward to printing from within a VM however, and was hoping my Ubuntu host machine would register the drivers being installed in the VM. As the print setup finished in the VM, the printer was also added to my Ubuntu host.